# Spring Integration annotation implementation with multiple gateway

Tags: annotations, spring-integration

I have a requirement to implement a serial web service call to 2 web services, say ServiceA followed by ServiceB. I implemented this using xml, having two separated gateways for each service and all, I wanted to know how to do this using annotation. How will I mention which service activator goes with which gateway.

Thanks

Comment: To help you we should see at least your XML. It is your specific task and we can't guess your business requirements.

Comment: I am not allowed to do that, I just wanted to know how spring integration annotation handles multiple gateways..

Comment: Which annotation? E.g. `@ServiceActivator` has `input` and `output` attrbiutes to connect using channels the underlying `ServiceActivatorHandler` with other endpoints. From other side each gateway's interface method can be `@Gateway` for Spring Integration flow. Really don't see entire picture what you mean. Sorry.